# Accessing the value from ASP page to ASPX.VB

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic

I have the asp page,  i fetch the value from query string and store in session .
**Code Is**

```
username = Trim(Request.querystring("username"))
Session("login")=username
NewUserName=Session("login")
```

Now I want to access this NewUserName value in the Asp.vb Page
**code is(.aspx page)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var login = '<%= Session["NewUserName"].ToString(); %>';
Session("login")=Login;
alert(login);

</script>
```

**Code is (.aspx.vb)**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load



Login = Session("login")
    If Session("login") Is Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx")
    End If
    Session("qid") = 0
End Sub
```

But This gives error and not access the value.

Comment: You cannot read session value using javascript.

Comment: than how to access the value from asp page to aspx.vb page

Comment: You will have to implement an asp to asp.net session bridge.. Here at codeplex there is an old article on have to do that from asp towards asp.net http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6378/ASP-to-ASP-NET-Session-Bridge-Using-a-Web-Service. You can implement it in the reverse way too, but then make sure to check your referrer so that your session objects can't be read by others..

Comment: You will have to use either database or local server files to "share" the Session between the two platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest bridge you could make to access the in-memory Classic ASPSESSION from an asp.net page, would be this:

- On the ASP end: An asp page to output your session, call it e.g. asp2netbridge.asp

  ```
  <%
  'Make sure it can be only called from local server '
  if (request.servervariables("LOCAL_ADDR") = request.servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR")) then
      if (Request.QueryString("sessVar") <> "") then
          response.write Session(Request.QueryString("sessVar"))
      end if
  end if
  %>
  ```
- On the .net end, a remote call to that asp page. :

  ```
  private static string GetAspSession(string sessionValue)
   {
      HttpWebRequest _myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://yourdomain.com/asp2netbridge.asp?sessVar=" + sessionValue));
      _myRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
      _myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
      if (_myRequest.CookieContainer == null)
          _myRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
      foreach (string cookieKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Keys)
      {
          ' it is absolutely necessary to pass the ASPSESSIONID cookie or you'll start a new session ! '
          if (cookieKey.StartsWith("ASPSESSIONID")) {
              HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieKey.ToString()];
              _myRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Domain)
                  ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
                  : cookie.Domain));
          }
      }
      try
      {
          HttpWebResponse _myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)_myRequest.GetResponse();

          StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
          return sr.ReadToEnd();
      }
      catch (WebException we)
      {
          return we.Message;
      }
  }
  ```